# binary search in array that contains range

Tags: algorithm

let's say that we have an ordered array contains elements like this ,

[1, 2-5, 6, 8-9, 11-13] , 2-5 is a range that represents 2, 3, 4 and 5, if we want to find "4" then index 1 (start from 0) is answer we need.

It's that possible we apply binary search like this type of elements with constans space and log(n) time?

Comment: After binary search, you need to compare the end elements like 2 and 5 and then infer where to search in first part or the second part

Comment: Yes. You just have to use custom comparison code, but it will still have the same complexity.

Comment: Why not have a go at it first, and then post your code if you bump into a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use **binary search**, the concept will also work with the ranges like a charm. Actually this is a concept commonly used to reduce time and space complexity, for example in `gap encoding`.
However you need to write it on your own instead of using any library as the library-method will probably not accept the ranges.

---

Let us briefly go through the execution of a binary search on your given input of `[1, 2-5, 6, 8-9, 11-13]` searching for the value **4** which is at index **1**.

The array `[1, 2-5, 6, 8-9, 11-13]` has length **5**, we decide for the index in the middle which is **2**. It reads the value `6` there. We search for the value `4` so we continue the search to the left.

We now reduced the search interval to `[1, 2-5, 6]`, length **3** and we decide for the middle index **1**. It reads `2-5`. As `4` is inside that range we have finished and return index **1** as result.

If for example it would read `5-7` there then we would continue the search to the left as **4** is not inside `5-7`. Analogously we would continue the search to the right if it would read `1-3`.

---

Here is an explanation of binary search with some pseudo-code: [Binary search algorithm at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

If you have problems implementing than just edit your question and show us what you have done so far, we will then adapt and help.

Comment: thanks, I got into trouble with range element search,  I understand it now, just apply the normal binary search but change the compare method(search number and range element) like "<" and "==".